# Compose scaffold padding values are too big when using enableEdgeToEdge()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, androidx

I'm using the `paddingValues` provided by the compose scaffold to account for the bottom bar in my app.

I also just implemented the new `enableEdgeToEdge()` feature provided by `androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0` to make the nav bar transparent.

Padding values ***before*** applying `enableEdgeToEdge()`:

```
PaddingValues(start=0.0.dp, top=0.0.dp, end=0.0.dp, bottom=80.0.dp)
```

Padding values ***after*** applying `enableEdgeToEdge()`:

```
PaddingValues(start=0.0.dp, top=50.333332.dp, end=0.0.dp, bottom=104.0.dp)
```

As you can see when using `enableEdgeToEdge()` it increases the padding values and the content becomes smaller. This has been tested on a Pixel 8 Pro.

I'm using `androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.00`

Full code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        TSViewerTheme {
            Scaffold (
                bottomBar = {
                    BottomNavBar(
                        navController = navController,
                    )
                },
                content = { paddingValues ->
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination, modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues).fillMaxSize()){
                        // Screens
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a fix for this or should I wait for an update of the dependencies?

Comparison screenshots:
[image: Not using enableEdgeToEdge()]
[image: Using enableEdgeToEdge()]

Comment: Can you please share your code to get more insights

Comment: Just added my code to the question

Comment: Did you add statusBarPadding for top app bar of your home screen may be that will be the reason. By seeing the UI only topAppBar screen is increased. If yes then remove the statusBarPadding method from modifier

Comment: The padding values are automatically generated, this works fine without enableEdgeToEdge(). If I remove the modifier then some UI elements will be hidden behind the bottom bar. This has to be a bug in the current versions of the libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution:

Add this line to all your scaffolds (Main + Screens):

```
contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp),
```

Answer (score 0):

What @BlazeCodeDev said is correct, but there's more to it, if you don't have a TopBar and BottomBar that will work, however if you do then you'll also have to add:

```
windowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp),
```

To the TopBar and BottomBar as well, for example:

```
Scaffold(
        contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp),
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                windowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp),
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "",
                    )
                },
```